# InfluxDB: Use last item from group by time interval

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to move some counters from a 15s daily measurement to a 5min weekly measurement:

```
SELECT * INTO company."week".foo_counters_5m
FROM company."day".foo_counters
WHERE time > now() - 1d
GROUP BY id,time(5m) fill(none) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing this question I found *an* answer using the `LAST(<field>)` function, not sure if it's the best one:

```
SELECT LAST(field1),LAST(field2)... INTO company."week".foo_counters_5m
FROM company."day".foo_counters
WHERE time > now() - 1d
GROUP BY id,time(5m) fill(none)
```

- Since `LAST` operates on fields, I'm quite this query must iterate through each item in the group.
- Unfortunately you can't do `LAST(*)`, you have to `SELECT` each field
- Tags (`id`) can be `SELECT`ed by including them in `GROUP BY`